# QML Can I Hold columns on GridView?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I want to get fixed columns on GridView like Gird.columns.

Is it possible?

I tried
verticalLayoutDirection,
flow,
snapMode on GridView.
but It was changed when window is resized.

for example,
there are 5 items on listmodel.
And I want just 1column, whenever window being resized.
But When window height size smaller than total height of items, It changed over 1 column...

```
Rectangle {
width: 300; height: 200

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        //onClicked: grid.currentIndex = -1
        //onEntered: grid.currentIndex = -1
    }


    Component {
    //Grid {
        id: contactDelegate
        //Grid {
        //columns: 1
        Item {
            width: grid.cellWidth; height: grid.cellHeight
            //columns: 1

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: grid.currentIndex = index
                onEntered: grid.currentIndex = index
            }

            Column {
                anchors.fill: parent
                Image { source: portrait; anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter }
                Text { text: name; anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter }
            }
        }
    }


    GridView {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: 80; cellHeight: 80
        //verticalLayoutDirection: GridView.TopToBottom
        //flow: GridView.FlowTopToBottom
        //snapMode: GridView.SnapToRow
        //columns: 1

        model: ContactModel {}
        delegate: contactDelegate
        highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue"; radius: 5 }
        focus: true

        flickableChildren: MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            //onClicked: grid.currentIndex = -1
            //onEntered: grid.currentIndex = -1
        }
        Component.onCompleted: currentIndex = -1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the orientation of the GridView, bind cellWidth or cellHeight to the GridView's width or height. Something like this:

```
GridView {
    ...
    cellWidth: grid.width/2       // if you want 2 columns for example
    cellHeight: grid.height/2     // OR, if you want only 2 rows (for horizontal flow)
    ...
}
```